# How to use randomness in Haskell to produce instances of a JSON "model"?

Tags: haskell, random, aeson, io-monad

I have this work where I have to read a JSON from a file and generate instances of it based on its model. I'm using aeson to serialize the objects, but I'm having a huge problem dealing with randomness to produce new objects.

Produce a new JSON based on what I get from file is pretty straight forward:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8    as ByteString
import qualified Data.Aeson                    as Aeson
import qualified Data.Aeson.Types              as Types
import qualified Data.Text

read :: String -> IO ()
read filePath = do
    json <- readFile filePath
    let Just parsedJSON =
            Data.Aeson.decode $ ByteString.pack json :: Maybe Aeson.Object
    let newJSON = fmap valueMapper parsedJSON
    print $ Aeson.encode newJSON


valueMapper :: Types.Value -> Types.Value
valueMapper value =
    case value of
        Types.String _      -> Types.String "randomValue"
        Types.Number _      -> Types.Number 0
        Types.Object object -> Types.Object $ fmap valueMapper object
        Types.Array  array  -> Types.Array $ fmap valueMapper array
```

My first attempt was to produce random values outside the IO. I used this function:

```hs
randomStr :: String
randomStr = take 10 $ randomRs ('a','z') $ unsafePerformIO newStdGen
```

Putting it on `valueMapper`:

```hs
valueMapper :: Types.Value -> Types.Value
valueMapper value =
    case value of
        Types.String _      -> Types.String $ Data.Text.pack randomStr
        Types.Number _      -> Types.Number 0
        Types.Object object -> Types.Object $ fmap valueMapper object
        Types.Array  array  -> Types.Array $ fmap valueMapper array
```

This "works", but all generated strings are the same, for every `String` field.

After a little research, I found out that if I want to produce different values for each `String` occurrence, I have to use the IO:

```hs
randomStr :: IO String
randomStr = replicateM 10 (randomRIO ('a', 'z'))
```

Now, I know that I have different strings for each call of `randomStr`... But I also have a type mismatch. Aeson `String` constructor to `Value` takes a `Data.Text`, but what I have is an `IO String`. As far as I know, my strings can never come back from `IO`.

I don't know if there is a way (hope so) to use the latest `randomStr` to compose my new JSON object. I also don't know if my approach is a good one. I'm open to suggestions about how can I put this to work, in my or any other way (some tips on how to write better code would be awesome too).

Comment: You might like [The IO Monad for People who Simply Don't Care](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html). Even if you don't, there are many, many tutorials lying around the web for understanding how to be productive with Haskell's IO model. Do we really need yet another one to be extemporized here on SO?

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for the tutorial. I dont know but it looks like I'm missing something that is so trivial

Comment: You already have a string "coming back from IO" in your program. `readFile :: String -> IO String`. Look at how that is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's relatively common when writing Haskell code to find yourself needing to convert a block of pure code into an IO action (or monadic code in some other action).  It comes with practice (and, as per the comments, after reading a *LOT* of tutorials), but I can show you my thought process as I work through your code example.

As you've discovered, trying to "hide" the IO using `unsafePerformIO` is a terrible idea.  The correct alternative is to rewrite the whole thing to operate in the IO monad, even though -- as you've seen -- rewriting `randomStr :: String` as `randomStr :: IO String` starts a chain of type mismatch errors that need to be resolved all the way to the top.

So, let's resolve them.  If `valueMapper` is going to make use of `randomStr :: IO String`, it too will need to operate in the IO monad:

```
valueMapper :: Types.Value -> IO Types.Value
```

(Note: If you make this change while using a live type-checking IDE, you'll find that the invocation of `valueMapper` in `read` is now flagged as a type error, as are the four branches in the case statement.)

Anyway, there's no problem with the outer structure of `valueMapper`, namely case-matching on the argument:

```
valueMapper value =
    case value of
        Types.String _      -> ???
        Types.Number _      -> ???
        Types.Object object -> ???
        Types.Array  array  -> ???
```

The difference is that now each of the `???` need to return an `IO Types.Value` instead of a `Types.Value`.  Let's start with an easy one.  Suppose we aren't going to generate random numbers yet, so we just want to convert the branch:

```
Types.Number _ -> Types.Number 0   -- pure version
```

to IO.  Here, we have a pure value `Types.Number 0 :: Types.Value`, and we want a monadic version.  That's what `return` is used for:

```
Types.Number _ -> return (Types.Number 0)   -- IO version
```

The next easiest is the string branch.  Right now, it looks like:

```
Types.String _ -> Types.String $ Data.Text.pack randomStr
```

where `randomStr` is an `IO String`.  It's still a mess of type errors, though.  That's because `randomStr` is an `IO String`, and we want to convert it to an `IO Types.Value`, but the construct:

```
Types.String $ Data.Text.pack _
```

is trying to convert a `String` to a `Types.Value` directly.  This is a common problem when working with monadic values.  We have an `IO a` that we want to convert to an `IO b`, but all we have is a function (here, `Types.String . Data.Text.pack`) to perform the direct conversion `a -> b`.  It would be helpful if we had some adapter function with signature:

```
foo :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
```

Fortunately, because IO, like all monads, is also a functor, we *do* have such an adapter:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
```

so, we can write the branch as:

```
Types.String _ -> fmap (Types.String . Data.Text.pack) randomStr
```

The last two, for objects and arrays, are tougher, though the solution is the same for each.  Taking the object branch, it's pure version looks like:

```
Types.Object object -> Types.Object $ fmap valueMapper object
```

In the pure version, `fmap` is used to apply `valueMapper :: Types.Value -> Types.Value` to each element of the list `object :: [Types.Value]` to get a new list of type `[Types.Value]` which is then converted to a `Types.Value` using the `Types.Object` constructor.

Let's tackle the `fmap` first.  We will still have `object :: [Types.Value]` from case matching on our pure argument `value`, so that hasn't changed.  But we want to apply the function `valueMapper :: Types.Value -> IO Types.Value` to each element of `object`.  The result will be a list of `Types.Value`, but in an IO monad context, so the full result type will be `IO [Types.Value]`.  That is, we want an adapter function:

```
bar :: (a -> IO a) -> [a] -> IO [a]
       ^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^    ^^^^^^- output list in IO context
                 |      `- input list
                 `- element-by-element conversion
```

Such a function already exists in more general form as `traverse`.  The full signature is:

```
traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

but specialized to a list traversable and an IO applicative, it's:

```
traverse :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]
```

Using it in our object branch, the result will look like:

```
Types.Object object -> Types.Object $ traverse valueMapper object
```

This still gives a type error because `traverse valueMapper object` returns an `IO [Types.Value]`, and we are trying to use the direct conversion `Types.Object :: [Types.Value] -> Types.Value` where we actually need a conversion `IO [Types.Value] -> IO Types.Value`.  This is the same problem we had with the string branch above, and the solution is to use `fmap`, so the following type checks:

```
Types.Object object -> fmap Types.Object (traverse valueMapper object)
```

You might want to take a moment here to perform the equivalent conversion on the array branch.

With those changes, `valueMapper` will type check.  Now the only issue is that it's usage in `read` won't type check.  The problem is the line:

```
let newJSON = fmap valueMapper parsedJSON
```

Here `parsedJSON` is of type `Aeson.Object` AKA `Types.Object` which is actually an alias for `HashMap Text Types.Value`.  The `fmap` here is used apply a pure `valueMapper :: Types.Value -> Types.Value` to each hashmap element in turn.

Now, we want to apply `valueMapper :: Types.Value -> IO Types.Value` to each element in turn and get the whole result in an IO context as `IO Aeson.Object`.  Fortunately, `Aeson.Object` AKA `HashMap` is `Traversable`, so the solution here is the same as for the object and array branches before -- replace the `fmap` with `traverse`:

```
let newJSON = traverse valueMapper parsedJSON
```

This still won't quite work, as the next line:

```
print $ Aeson.encode newJSON
```

expects `newJSON` to be a pure `Aeson.Object`, but the return value of the `traverse` call is in the IO context, so it's `IO Aeson.Object`.  We could try to rewrite this `print` line to expect `newJSON :: IO Aeson.Object`.  For example, the following would work:

```
print =<< fmap Aeson.encode newJSON
```

However, there's actually a much simpler way.  In a do-block, the left arrow `<-` notation can be used for this purpose.  Where:

```
let newJSON = traverse valueMapper parsedJSON
```

assigns `newJSON` an IO action of type `IO Aeson.Object`, the alternative:

```
newJSON <- traverse valueMapper parsedJSON
```

"unwraps" the IO action to assign `newJSON` the underlying `Aeson.Object` for use in subsequent statements.  So:

```
newJSON <- traverse valueMapper parsedJSON
print $ Aeson.encode newJSON
```

will type check.

One more stylistic note.  It's common to use the infix synonym `<$>` in place of `fmap` to apply pure functions to IO actions.  So, the final program would look like this:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8    as ByteString
import qualified Data.Aeson                    as Aeson
import qualified Data.Aeson.Types              as Types
import qualified Data.Text

import Control.Monad
import System.Random

read :: String -> IO ()
read filePath = do
    json <- readFile filePath
    let Just parsedJSON =
            Aeson.decode $ ByteString.pack json :: Maybe Aeson.Object
    newJSON <- traverse valueMapper parsedJSON
    print $ Aeson.encode newJSON

valueMapper :: Types.Value -> IO Types.Value
valueMapper value =
    case value of
        Types.String _      -> Types.String . Data.Text.pack <$> randomStr
        Types.Number _      -> return $ Types.Number 0
        Types.Object object -> Types.Object <$> traverse valueMapper object
        Types.Array  array  -> Types.Array <$> traverse valueMapper array

randomStr :: IO String
randomStr = replicateM 10 (randomRIO ('a', 'z'))
```